# Handle completion handler in function

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have this function in my helper class.

```
func requestAllCars() -> [Car] {
    var carList = [Car]()
    let username:String = prefs.valueForKey("USERNAME") as String
    let apikey:String = prefs.valueForKey("APIKEY") as String
    self.requestObject(.getCarsUrl, params: ["apikey":apikey, "username":username], completionHandler: {( response, error ) in
        if let response = response {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder(response.responseObject!)
            if let decoders = decoder.array {
                carList.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
                for subdecoder in decoders {
                    println("de autos \(subdecoder)")
                    carList.append(Car(subdecoder))
                }
            }
        }
    })
    return carList
}
```

But it isn't populating the carList. I guess because the async call.. How can I solve this when I do

```
var carlist = helperclass.requestAllCars()
```

Answer (score 1):

You create a [Car] at the start and then you call an async handler and then return the [Car] and then the async runs. Thats what currently happens.

If you want to set an array to that functions return value you have to add an inout parameter: `func requestAllCars(inout arr: [Car])`

And at the top level inside the async handler you do:

```
for subdecoder in decoders {
    println("de autos \(subdecoder)")
    arr.append(Car(subdecoder))
}
```

This will fill up your array that you pass as arr when that async is run.

So by doing this:

```
var carList = [Car]()
helperclass.requestAllCars(carList)
```

After the async is run carList will be filled.